# Where is the Event.ClientGuid field?

Tags: metadata, configuration, ant

Following a failed Ant deployment, I have these error messages:

> All Component Failures:
>   1.  objects/Event.object (Event.**ClientGuid**) -- Error: Could not resolve standard field's name. (line 65, column 13)
>   2.  objects/Event.object (Event.**OriginalInstanceDateTime**) -- Error: Could not resolve standard field's name. (line 98, column 13)
>   3.  objects/Event.object (Event.**IsException**) -- Error: Could not resolve standard field's name. (line 88, column 13)

How come these standard fields do not exist in my destination org, but in my source org ?

From my point of view there are two options:

- either this is due to a specific combination of metadata in the package.xml Ant file
- or these fields can be made available using a specific configuration option that I can not find

I searched for this in the options and via metadata, and only found that this specific field exists on the source pod (CS81) and not the destination (CS80).

Community, I turn to you, as I have surfed all the docs and search engines in the web with no success.

Comment: Interesting. It's [documented](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_event.htm) without an API version, which as far as I can tell, implies it's been available since API 10.0. No idea why it would be missing from an org.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fields ClientGuid, IsException and OriginalInstanceDateTime are not just added when the feature "Advanced Calendaring" is turned on, but also when you set up an Outlook Configuration. 
A requirement for the Outlook Configuration, if you want the fields to appear, is that you add Events as a Data Set with the checkbox "Sync recurring events" checked on.